# How can I set a default value of 0 to a SQLite table column?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using C# to create a SQLite table:

```
db2.CreateTable<Phrase>();

public class Phrase : IPhrase
{
    public Phrase()
    {
    }

    [PrimaryKey, NotNull]
    public bool Favorite { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int Modified { get; set; }
    public string English { get; set; }
    public bool Hidden { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way that I can give the value of Hidden a default value of 0 ?

Comment: I'm kind of a noob with C# and SQLite, but wouldn't it be easier to just add a default value to your class on C# code, and when you insert/update, the value is persisted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boolean fields are 0 (or false) by default if you don't provide a value.

Also, you seem to be setting a boolean 'favorite' as your primary key? You probably intended the 'categoryid' to be the key?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
public class Phrase : IPhrase
{
    public Phrase()
    {
    }

    [PrimaryKey, NotNull]
    public bool Favorite { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int Modified { get; set; }
    public string English { get; set; }
    [NotNull, Default(value: 0)]
    public bool Hidden { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I completely agree.  I'm just adding in the code part he was asking about.